# GlobalSign SSL Certificate Installation

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have the server.key, server.crt (certificate file) and server-ca (Cert chain file) for an Ubuntu server. Under /etc/apache2/ there is an apache2.conf file, which has no details of the SSL certificate. Inside the sites-enabled directory, there are many "xyz-ssl.conf" configuration files that contain SSL details of many domains.
I am not sure where to put the renewed SSL certificate details.

Comment: Look at the apache docs, there is a whole section on configuring ssl.

Comment: On Debian family including Ubuntu, there should never be any files in sites-enabled, only symlinks to files in sites-available. However if you _read_ those symlinks, e.g. with grep, they provide (and thus appear to contain) the content from the linked files. If the files are already organized correctly, which is impossible for us to tell, you should presumably put the 'renewed' cert&key in place of the existing ones that are presumably expiring and need to be replaced -- unless of course you or someone else made a mistake.

Comment: If you know the name of the site you could maybe check with `grep -r /etc/apache2/ "sitename" ` in which site vhost config you need to look